# Localhost WAMP site is showing duplicate records while production server is not

Tags: php

I recently installed WAMP on a new laptop and I am seeing odd behavior.
I have a PHP page connecting to a MySQL server running the following code:

```
    /* Build table of team availability */
    $availSQL = "SELECT
                    `security`.`email` AS `email`,
                    IF(`availability`.`startHours` = '00:00:00', 'Not assigned or on PTO', `availability`.`desc`) AS `desc`,
                    `availability`.`startHours` AS `startHours`,
                    `availability`.`endHours` AS `endHours`
                FROM
                    `availability`
                INNER JOIN
                    `security` ON `security`.`availability` = `availability`.`code`
                ORDER BY
                    `availability`.`desc` ASC,
                    `security`.`email` ASC;";
    /* echo $availSQL; */
    $result = $con->query($availSQL);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($count > 0) {
        $currShift = "";
        $teamAvailability = "<hr /><h3>Standard Release Management Team Availability:</h3>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $email = $row['email'];
            $explodeEmail = explode("@", $email);
            $explodeName = explode(".", $explodeEmail[0]);
            $rmName = ucfirst($explodeName[0]) . " " . ucfirst($explodeName[1]);
            $desc = $row['desc'];
            $startHours = date('g:i a', strtotime($row['startHours']));
            $endHours = date('g:i a', strtotime($row['endHours']));
            if (($currShift !== $desc)) {
                $currShift = $desc;
                if ($desc !== "Not assigned or on PTO") {
                    $teamAvailability .= "<hr /><h4>$desc | <i>Coverage from $startHours ET to $endHours ET</i></h4>";
                }
                else {
                    $teamAvailability .= "<hr /><h4>$desc</h4>";
                }
                $teamAvailability .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;$rmName<br />";
            }
            else {
                $currShift = $desc;
                $teamAvailability .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;$rmName<br />";
            }
        }
    }
```

When I open the page the code is running, but I am seeing each record displayed twice.
Please see the attached screenshot showing six rows returned in the database, but 12 rows displayed in the browser.
The same exact code behaved as expected in my old laptop, so I think this must be some PHP or MySQL setting, but I cannot figure out what it could be.
Screenshot showing difference between query results and browser interpretation:
[image: Screenshot showing difference between query results and browser interpretation]

I have run the code on my old laptop and new laptop and have verified there is some setting which is different on the new laptop.